# Chrome 64bit font face render

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts, font-face

I'm having a problem with the new Chrome 64 bit.
It doesn't render the custom fonts in regular, only in bold.

At the top of the image is how it show be. At the bottom is what it's actually rendered.
[image]

Here's what i got:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'icons';
    src: url('../fonts/icons.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/icons.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
         url('../fonts/icons.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('../fonts/icons.ttf') format('truetype'), 
         url('../fonts/icons.svg#untitled_fontregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
.icon {
    font-family: 'icons'; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    line-height: 1;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I've tested it in Firefox, Safari and Opera and it's all good.
Any suggestions...?

Thanks

Comment: Could you recreate this on jsfiddle for me?

Comment: Ok, here...http://jsfiddle.net/KupGest/75cwuwax/

Comment: It looks fine on my screen haha. (In chrome)

Comment: What's your version?

Comment: Version 39.0.2171.71 (64-bit)

Comment: Same thing here... I've tested it in multiple Macs and it kept giving the same "error in Chrome.

Comment: But ok, i've discovered this little hack in case anyone ever has the same problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed a little "hack" that worked.
I've just added a "translateZ" to the font and now it's fine,

```
.icon {
    font-family: 'icons'; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    line-height: 1;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;

    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

But I still don't know why this is happening.

Comment: Thanks - this hack worked for me too.  For me, I've noticed that it's working fine on my retina display, but on an externally attached monitor, Chrome is getting confused and over-boldening fonts that have `antialiased` applied.